# How to remove black bands in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to remove the black bands on the simulator in Xcode. I have this problem only with my projects with the latest version of Xcode and when I create a new project I also have this problem. The only thing I did is to add iOS simulator because when I create the project I only have the Mac simulator. Any idea how to fix it?

This is the code with the issue (it's a blank project)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Image with black bands open simulator:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the aspect ratio of the device's screen not matching the aspect ratio of your content.

Maybe you can try putting

```
    .resizable()
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

or

```
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
```

underneath your image, see what that does.

Comment: it changes the size of the image and we can see it entirely but the black bands are still there